# Line Graph with equidistant x-axis values python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis, linegraph

I have a set of data consisting of time and values.

> [image: Blockquote]

Using this code I get:

```
time=['07:45','8:15','8:45','9:35','10:15','15:05','16:05']
value=[3,8,12,54,23,12,5]
plt.plot(time,value)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see there is a huge gap between 10:15 and 15:15. I want to have an x-axis that also reflects the time difference between one recording and the other. In other words I need the gap between 10:15 and 15:15 to be larger then between 07:45 and 8:15. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what you're asking is the default. But of course you need to actually plot time values, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to convert the strings in numerical values for the times:

```
time=['07:45','8:15','8:45','9:35','10:15','15:05','16:05']
d=[]
for i in time:
    c=i.split(':')
    d.append((float(c[0])-7)*60+float(c[1]))

print d
```

We have associated to each time the number of minutes that separate it from 7 o'clock. 
Then we can make the plot:

```
value=[3,8,12,54,23,12,5] 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(d,value)
```

and also change the ticks:

```
value=[3,8,12,54,23,12,5] 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(d,value)
plt.xticks(d,time)
plt.show()
```

If you want to have different x-ticks, you just manually write them in a list, for example:

```
time2=['8:00','10:00','12:00','14:00','16:00']
```

then you convert the list as we did previously:

```
d2=[]
for i in time2:
    c=i.split(':')
    d2.append((float(c[0])-7)*60+float(c[1]))

print d2
```

and you change the ticks accordingly:

```
plt.xticks(d2,time2)
```

Comment: But that would only change the labeling. What I need to do is change the x-axis (spacing between one value and the other). I edited the original question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @CXB I edited my answer with what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the other answerer didn't see my comment. What I meant by "to actually plot time values" is to convert the times to `datetime` objects. Then plotting them leads to equidistant labels by default. One may beautify them by specifying an H:M format if desired.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

time=['07:45','8:15','8:45','9:35','10:15','15:05','16:05']
truetime = [datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M") for t in time]
value=[3,8,12,54,23,12,5]

plt.plot(truetime,value)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I did it manually since I wasn't aware of the existence of that package. I suggest the questioner to follow your solution @CXB